# Xamarin - IOS UIPickerView - Calling Select method doesn't trigger Selected event handler

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I create my UIPickerView as following 
`UIPickerView pv = new UIPickerView(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(10, 20, 100, 70));`

On a button click, I call the following.

```
public void HandleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int index = (int)pv.SelectedRowInComponent(0);

        if (index == 0)
            index = 1;
        else if (index == 1)
            index = 2;
        else if (index == 2)
            index = 0;

        pv.Select(index, 0, false);

    }
```

The last line in above code, doesn't trigger Selected event, but if I change UIPickerView option myself by interacting with UI, then Selected is called.

Here is my UIPickerViewModel class.

```
    public class PickerModel : UIPickerViewModel
{
    string[] values = new string[] {"Item 1", "Item 2","Item 3" };
    public event EventHandler ItemSelected;

    public override nint GetRowsInComponent(UIPickerView pickerView, nint component)
    {
        return values.Length;
    }

    public override nint GetComponentCount(UIPickerView pickerView)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public override string GetTitle(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
    {
        return values[(int)row].ToString();
    }

    public override void Selected(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
    {
        ItemSelected(pickerView, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

}
```

Is it the expected behavior, or do I need to do something differently in order to trigger Selected event? In Android, setting Spinner's selected index in code triggers selected.

Comment: That is expected behavior, `selectRow:inComponent:animated:` does not fire the selector `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:`. If it did, in your example, you would be in an infinite event loop.

Comment: @SushiHangover  I don't agree with you on your statement about infinite loop. Button click causes next item to be selected. HandleClick is not the event handler for the selected event. I have the same logic in Android and it works just fine.

Comment: Ah, I assumed ItemSelected == HandleClick, but it does not matter anyway, just call your `ItemSelected` method after your `pv.Select`, or if it is not visible, manually call the `Selected` override, otherwise you can use KVO and act upon the uipicker observer calls